# What is this .template file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, asynchronous

I just downloaded the latest version of [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), and I noticed a file I haven't seen before (in any project). There is a index-async.html.template file within the app folder. I know enough to know what asynchronous loading is, but I have never seen a .template file used in web development before. Does anyone out there know what this is used for, and if there is any benefit to using the `index-async.html.template` vs. just the regular `index-async.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be used solely when using the Angular-Seed update feature.  If you look into the `update-angular.sh` file in the `scripts` directory you find this:

```
# Update the inlined angular-loader in app/index-async.html
sed '/@@NG_LOADER@@/{
    s/@@NG_LOADER@@//g
    r app/lib/angular/angular-loader.min.js
}' app/index-async.html.template > app/index-async.html
```

So, it seems that Angular-Seed will auto replace some dependencies when you use the update.  It does this by token replacing in `.template` and then overwriting `index-async.html`.

So, it isn't to be used in web development.

Comment: So it the .template only improves angular-seeds performance, not the site itself?

Comment: I think that angular-seed uses the `.sh` file to update to a newer version of angular (during development).  So, it is used in that feature.